# Creating layer in ArcMap from SQL Server database table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, sql-server

Is it possible to create a layer from an SQL Server table instead of a shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

> The Query Layers functionality supports access to any of the databases
>   supported by ArcGIS (Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, DB2 and Informix)
>   and any of the spatial types available for those database platforms.

This blog posting on [Query Layers @ ArcGIS 10](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/04/14/query-layers-arcgis-10/) should provide a good intro, and it leads into the relevant [online help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_query_layer/00s50000000n000000/).